# How do I share C++ source code files between projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, c++-cli

I'm writing a cross-platform application. One version will work under Win32 and the second on Windows Phone.

I'd like to reuse my C++ core - especially that there are no platform dependencies inside, STL only. I order to do so, I want to use the same source files in two projects: static Win32 library (.lib) and Windows Phone Component (C++/CLI).

How can I configure these two projects to use exactly the same source and header files?

---

OK, let's take an example. Let's say, that I have project:

```
MyApp.Library [win32 lib]
    myClass.cpp
    myClass.h
```

This library is compiled to .DLL file and then imported in a Win32 application:

```
MyApp.Win32App [win32 C#]
```

Since Win32 is not compatible with Windows Phone on the binary level, I cannot use that library directly. But since the library uses only STL, I can create a Windows Phone component, put all its sources there, and build.

```
MyApp.Component [Windows Phone component]
    myClass.cpp
    myClass.h
```

I want these two files to be exactly the same ones as used in the library. How should I organize the project to achieve this effect?

Comment: Care to comment on downvote?

Comment: What about having the main application(s) and the library within one solution, and have matching build configurations for all of them?

Comment: @Spook Not one of the downvoters here, but your question still appears a bit unclear.

Comment: @Spook As for your edits: (I'm actually not that well versed with VS) It looks like you need two binary versions of your library, created from the same sources. Usually (as I mentioned before) you'll have 2 different build settings for your library project to match for what it should be linked in. I'm not sure if it's possible for VS solutions to refer project imports from the same solution, by matching for their build settings; but I'd guess so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add source code from a common location to multiple projects. I do that a lot; I have code in a common directory that is at the same level in the directory hierarchy as most of my project files. It's simply a matter of adding .h and .cpp files from the common directory to your various projects.

I did notice that VisualStudio gets a little cranky and difficult if you use a network drive for common source, so I don't do that. But so long as all of your source code is on local disks, and the IDE knows where to find them, there is no problem having the same source file in very many projects.

Comment: so you did in a sense not really solve the issue - unless having mutiple instances of same file is your solution - short of putting shared into a lib of its own, is there really no way of adding them relative???

Comment: @serup It doesn't take multiple instances of a source file to have different projects in different folders refer to the same source file. I do have an amendment to my previous answer: VisualStudio is OK with a project that references sources on network drives. It gets unhappy with project files that are on network drives. I do develop on several machines on the same local network, and many of my projects include classes from my homespun class library on a network drive.

Comment: yes I found a simple solution that works for me  - you can see my answer

Comment: @Logicrat, isn’t it a bad practice to share same file in many projects? I mean there could easily be conflicts if you try to edit it from two different projects? Doesn’t VS go crazy when you try to ‘go to a definition’? Why don’t you put these files in a shared library instead?

Comment: @GregoryStein I've been doing it for many years. Once in a great while there is a little snag, generally fixed by doing a "clean project". I don't want a shared library because I build in many different configurations. In fact, a lot of my code is compiled by VS in Windows and by Xcode on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

one way is to put all .hpp and .cpp files into a seperate folder - call it "Shared".

Then add an additional include Directory inside your solution configuration property - this directory must be a relative path.

Then add **ONLY** the .cpp files relative from that shared folder into your project

NB! If you have include "stdafx.h" inside your .cpp files in the Shared folder, then comment those out.

Comment: Many of my shared `.cpp` files include `"stdafx.h"`. Each project file has its own local copy of stdafx. In some cases, I have to add the project directory to the bottom of the list of directories to include, but that allows me to keep the functionality of precompiled headers.

Comment: @Logicrat only had issues with unittests - had to set unittest project to NOT use precompiled headers